# SymmetricDS - Detected losing row for batch [[batch]] for missing foreign key parent [[table]]: [[id]]

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-replication, symmetricds, symmetric

I'm having an issue with SymmetricDS when it comes to sync.

So the issue is as follows, I have an HQ (1) and one Agency (2). This issue does not happen in the HQ --> Agency route, and only in the Agency --> HQ route.

The error is as follows:

```
[sede-000] [DefaultDatabaseWriterConflictResolver] [sede-000-dataloader-1665] Detected losing row for batch preagencia002-680 for missing foreign key parent agencias:7090efee-379d-44f7-bb58-4ca4e596c62f
```

It seems some rows are being lost in the transaction. There's no error in the incoming batch table or anything.

The databases are the same, meaning they started with the same image, FK, Data, everything is the same, I then installed SymmetricDS in the HQ as the registration computer (So it could be the hq). Afterwards I connected the Agency to the HQ's symmetric and it registered sucessfully. All fine so far.

It worked fine for a few months, all data was being synced correctly in both ways. Then the client decided to do some connectivity tests where they unplugged the network cable in the middle of a DB save, that's fine as all data is being saved to a local DB and everything is afterwards replicated to the HQ when connection is restored.

But after these network tests I started getting the above errors where the Agency successfully pushes the data to the HQ and then the HQ can't seem to update/add rows due to a foreign key? I have confirmed that all data related to this foreign key is there: "7090efee-379d-44f7-bb58-4ca4e596c62f" exists in the "agencies" column and it's all there, all FK constraints are all there too.

I'm at a loss here. Keeping in mind that it stopped working in the PreProd environment, still works perfectly in the dev env. Could it be that these network tests broke something in SymmetricDS?

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Edit: To reiterate on what's being said.

The agency foreign key exists in the HQ database, so there's no reason why it should happen. Is there any way I can force any kind of resolution? Because this has been happening for a while and I'm still nowhere near resolving this issue.

Comment: Were the same records changed on both the source and the target databases?
Are the tables on both the source and the target defined the same?
What does the DDL look like for the tables involved?

Comment: @PhilipMarzullo the records were added on the Agency database, SymmetricDS then sends the data successfully to the HQ, however, it's when it consumes that gives out the error. The tables are defined exactly the same, as they're both copies of the same database that didn't have symmetric installed, I installed and configured symmetric after creating the DBs in the respective servers.

Comment: @PhilipMarzullo keeping in mind that the replication worked up until 2 days ago where the network tests were conducted

Comment: The log message that you posted isn't an error. It is an info message telling you that there was a conflict and it resulted in a losing row. Do you see an error coming from the database in your symmetric.log file?

Comment: Out of curiosity - as you already have Postgres as both ends, why not use Postgres' built-in replication support? The problem with SymmetricDS is that it runs as a trigger, which (in my experience) has been no end of problems.

Comment: @Dai The architecture was quite the issue, we needed everything to be master to master but have fine control over what tables are replicated, SymmetricDS seemed like the ideal choice, I tried the Postgresql replication but it had feedback loops and thus was cut out.